# how to change part of the url from capital to small letters after the directory path is changed apache/httpd

Tags: regex, linux, apache, web-services

I want to be short and sweet. My website address was this 
`https://www.example.com/ABCD/index.php`

To make it convenient for users, I changed the ABCD directory to abcd (small case). Now users type 
`https://www.example.com/abcd/index.php`

However if users come to my site from google, there it is still cached as 
`https://www.example.com/ABCD/index.php` 
and therefore they are not able to login.

I searched google and stack overflow and the closest effective I found is [here].[1](http://brianflove.com/2014/08/11/lowercase-your-uris/) i.e.

in http.conf

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
</IfModule>
```

and in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

However it is also not working in my case. because it take users from 
`https://www.example.com/ABCD/index.php?gene=MYH7` 
to 
`https://www.example.com/var/www/html/example.com/?gene=MYH7`

Could anyone experienced please help me to correct this rule. All I want is to direct users to 
`https://www.example.com/abcd/index.php` 
If they type 
`https://www.example.com/ABCD/index.php`

Here is the .htaccess in my web root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Added by Mian to direct all traffic to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.org%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]

# Added by Mian for url capital to small.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Short and sweet, indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems not to work inside a .htaccess.   I have the following working in my Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 rewriteengine on
 RewriteMap lc int:tolower
 RewriteRule "^/([A-Z]*)/(.*)$"  "${lc:$1}/$2"  [R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

The following rule will lowercase the first part of the URL as soon as there is one uppercase character.

```
RewriteRule "^/([^/]*[A-Z][^/]*)/(.*)$"  "${lc:$1}/$2"  [R=301]
```

Comment: Still the same output like the one I got from above.
Here is my .htaccess filed store in root directory. <br />
{<br />
RewriteEngine On<br />

# Added by Mian to direct all traffic to https<br />
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]<br />
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.<br />
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.org%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]<br />

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]<br />
#RewriteRule ^ ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L,NE]<br />

RewriteRule "^(.*[A-Z].*)$" "${lc:$1}" [R=301,L] <br />
}

Comment: Of course, you didn't show that first rule in your OP.   But it's that one that gets executed.

Comment: Ohh so it is causing the issue. What should I do now? Let me add this to the question.

Comment: If you don't need it, throw the first 3 lines out.

Comment: But I need it because this is directing all the traffic to https.

Comment: OK, I'm trying myself now by calling APPRAISE, which doesn't function, while appraise does.   Check all your configuration files for rewrite rules.  Does the APPRAISE folder still exist?

Comment: No APPRAISE is changed to appraise

Comment: Add the rewritemap to the .htaccess.  You do reload Apache after each modification?  (I never use .htaccess, don't know if it's necessary to reload)

Comment: Not after .htaccess modification. I think it is not necessary because the changes were taking place as soon as data is stored.

Comment: Can you please remove your four lines and replace them by  the one I gave you?

Comment: I tried but same answer. I have one more redirect rule too. Sorry to say just realize now.

Comment: I have tried everything, it does not work inside a .htaccess.  Inside a virtualhost in the apache conf: immediately.

Comment: It is working. but is it possible to only change the directory like ACGV or APPRAISE to small case instead of the whole url. Currently, it is converting the whole url to small case so I have to convert the images name and a tag to small case or they will not work.

Comment: Sure, is the directory always and only the first part?   But first tell me: how did you succeed?

Comment: yes it is always the first part after the example.com/directoryname/.....

Comment: And the solution was?

Comment: so i have some images inserted in the document like <a href= ..> Their name is capital and this script convert them in the document to small too and then the picture dont load.

Comment: with your above solution, the virtual host part

Comment: But you didn't accept it.  That's not very nice ;-)  I will modify my solution.

Comment: I can't test it now.   Will you try asap?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166420/discussion-between-mian-asbat-ahmad-and-gerard-h-pille).

Comment: One more change: R=301, or the search engines will never change their databases.

Answer (score 0):

Change your rule with this one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^ ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L,NE]
```

**Changes:**

- Redirect path starts with a trailing slash. If trailing slash is missing then `DocumentRoot` path is appended by Apache as you're seeing in your redirect rule.
- Avoid capturing value from `RewriteRule` as your .htaccess might be in a sub-directory.
- `%{REQUEST_URI}` represents full path from site root

Make sure to use a new browser for testing.

Comment: I kept the httpd.conf unchanged and replaced the above four lines with the two lines you suggested in .htaccess and I got a wrong path i.e. 
``` https://www.example.com/abcd/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php ```

It seems for every capital letter it is writing one index.php plus the last one.

Do you want me to remove the code from httpd.conf and only add this in  .htaccess?

Comment: BTW I think you are the right person to help me. Author of the book Java regular expression :)

Comment: Keep this rule before any other rule Just below `RewriteEngine On` line and retest from a new browser. This rule is fully tested and working on my Apache.

Comment: when I add your mentioned two lines, the website is redirected to https://www.example.org/?gene=MYH7

Comment: What was the original URL you entered in browser? Did you disable browser cache? Lastly show your latest .htaccess in question.